# Nuget Server Repository - Page not found 404

Tags: nuget-server

I'm totally desperate. I've been trying to install Nuget.Server v3.2.1.0 for two days now.
I followed the installation instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server, but it doesn't work.

I suspect that the routing doesn't work properly.

My Web.config looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />

    <!-- maxRequestLength is specified in Kb -->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" maxRequestLength="30720" />
  </system.web>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseHostHeaderForRequestUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="requireApiKey" value="true" />
    <add key="apiKey" value="MyApiKey" />
    <add key="packagesPath" value="D:\TFS-Workspaces\Fachit360\Playground\NuGet Server\NuGet Server\Packages" />
    <add key="cacheFileName" value="" />
    <add key="allowOverrideExistingPackageOnPush" value="false" />
    <add key="ignoreSymbolsPackages" value="true" />
    <add key="enableDelisting" value="false" />
    <add key="enableFrameworkFiltering" value="false" />
    <add key="enableFileSystemMonitoring" value="true" />
    <add key="allowRemoteCacheManagement" value="false" />
    <add key="initialCacheRebuildAfterSeconds" value="15" />
    <add key="cacheRebuildFrequencyInMinutes" value="60" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".nupkg"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".nupkg" mimeType="application/zip" />
    </staticContent>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="31457280" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      ...
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And here is my development environment:
- Visual Studio 2017 Pro (15.9.12)
- Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC
- IIS Express 10.0 (Visual Studio integrated)

The installation is very simple. The overview page is also displayed:
[image: Pic1]

What I find confusing is that the Default.aspx file contains the following:

`Click <a href="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/nuget/Packages") %>">here</a> to view your packages.`

And in the file `NuGetODataConfig.cs` the following is configured:

```cs
NuGetV2WebApiEnabler.UseNuGetV2WebApiFeed(
    config,
    "NuGetDefault,
    "nuget"
    "PackagesOData,
    enableLegacyPushRoute: true);
```

Anyway, when I click on "Click here to view your packages", I get the error: "Page not found - 404".

Does anyone have an idea why that might be? I am at the end of my Latin.

Many greetings

**Update**

I forgot to mention that I also tried to release the project on a Windows Server 2012 R2. Exactly the same problem.

And it's strange that you can find the following packages in my project references:
- Nuget.Core
- Nuget.server
- Nuget.Server.Core
- Nuget.Server.V2

Then why does the start page talk about Nuget.Server 3.2.1.0?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Nope. I use now the free version of ProGet from inedo.com. It works fine and can much more.